# Change orientation at runtime

Tags: android, android-orientation

I'm new to android my question is, Is it possible to change orientation programmatically? If yes, how can we do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Also add this in your manifest file (under activity):

```
android:configChanges = "orientation"
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); to force orientation

Answer (score 3):

yes this one possible

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);