# Android default screen orientation

Tags: java, android

In my manifest file, I set

```
    android:screen orientation="portrait"
```

for my MainActivity. I did this so that my initial tutorial can work well. After the initial tutorial has concluded, I now want my MainActivity to behave normally ie when the user rotates the device let it change by itself(the default behaviour). Is there a way to that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `android:screenorientation="portrait"` from Manifest First .

From Run-time

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Also add this in your manifest file (under activity):

```
android:configChanges = "orientation"
```

> [Change orientation at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837184/change-orientation-at-runtime)

http://techblogon.com/android-screen-orientation-change-rotation-example/

Comment: how can u do that at runtime

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366706/how-to-lock-orientation-during-runtime

Comment: @MichaelPeter : Did you check above url .I hope it will helps you

Comment: I was able to figure it out after checking that URL. After my initial tutorial completes, I make a call to    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER) and this sets it back to default behavior

Answer (score 1):

remove  `android:screenorientation="portrait"` from your manifest, and make sure rotation is on in your device

Comment: How can u do that at runtime

Comment: kt code-> requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT

Answer (score 1):

Remove 
android:screenOrientation="portrait" from manifest file
and make sure your device setting isint set to "locked rotation"

also android:screenOrientation="portrait" works for whole manifest file level and also it works individually for activity tag level in manifest, so if android:screenOrientation="portrait" is added in activity tag level ,
remove it from there too.